# Retrieve originating package of warning object

Tags: python, python-3.9, contextmanager

**Task**

For a given block of code implying the use of different packages (eg. pandas, numpy, etc) i need to retrieve a list of all the warnings created.

**Partial solution**

with `warnings.catch_warnings(record=True)` i am able to "catch" all the warnings in the list but because stacklevel is almost always 2  when doing `warnings.warn` this means i am able to get a reference only to the caller not the exact piece of code where `warnings.warn` was called (having that is then quite easy to extract the package name)

**Current solution**

With context manager i can build a wrapper around warnings.warn method so that i am able to hook into it and grab the originating file/package of the column.

```py
class MyWarningsCtx:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_warn = warnings.warn
        self.warnings = []

        #
        def new_warn(*args, **kwargs):
            frame = inspect.stack()[1]
            p = frame[0].f_code.co_filename
            obj = {"message": args[0], "path": p}
            self.warnings.append(obj)
            self.old_warn(*args, **kwargs)

        warnings.warn = new_warn
        return self.warnings

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        warnings.warn = self.old_warn
```

To test this i'm using the following

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame([['1990', 'a', 5, 4, 7, 2], ['1991', 'c', 10, 1, 2, 0], ['1992', 'd', 2, 1, 4, 12], ['1993', 'a', 5, 8, 11, 6]],
                      columns=('Date', 'best', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))

    df.lookup(df.index, df['best'])
    print("\n\n\n\n")
    with MyWarningsCtx() as wrngs:
        df.lookup(df.index, df['best'])
        print("\n\n\n\n")
        print({"parsed_warnings": wrngs})
```

```
path_to_current_folder/test_ctx_warnings.py:30: FutureWarning: The 'lookup' method is deprecated and will beremoved in a future version.You can use DataFrame.melt and DataFrame.locas a substitute.
  df.lookup(df.index, df['best'])





path_to_env/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4553: FutureWarning: The 'lookup' method is deprecated and will beremoved in a future version.You can use DataFrame.melt and DataFrame.locas a substitute.
  warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=2)





{'parsed_warnings': [{'message': "The 'lookup' method is deprecated and will beremoved in a future version.You can use DataFrame.melt and DataFrame.locas a substitute.", 'path': '/path_to_env/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py'}]}
```

Now there are a few things which I wish you could help me with:

1. Would there be any other option to achieve what am I trying without "hooking" and replacing the warnings.warn method?
2. First df.lookup call will, as expected, throw the warning containing the line of the callee (stacklevel 2). Second call of the df.lookup, just because is inside the with block, is already throwing the warning but with a different path (exactly where the warnings.warn was called - this is what i'm interested in. Why?  What am i missing?
3. Of course the printed {"parsed_warnings"} looks as i want because i am still using `inspect` to get the file. But it would also be fine even if i didn't use the `inspect`. Even if i did only something like this (below) i would still get the exact line of `warnings.warn` call. Not sure what am i missing

```py
def new_warn(*args, **kwargs):
    self.old_warn(*args, **kwargs)
```

4. How confident would you be with going with such workaround into production?